# Remove multiple elements from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, fancybox, caption

I'd like to remove multiple specific elements from my array before it displays. Here is the code I have but it results in none of the elements being displayed:

```
$('[data-fancybox]').on('click', function() {
  var visibleLinks = $('.fancybox:visible');

  $.fancybox.open( visibleLinks, {
      //options go here
caption: function (instance, item) {
        var caption, link, collectTags, tags, filterTags, filteredTags;

        function format(tpl, binding) {
            if (typeof binding != 'function') return format(tpl, function (_, name) {
                return binding[name];
            });
            return tpl.replace(/\$(\w+)/g, binding);
        }

        caption = $(this).data('caption');
        link = format('<br>See more pictures', item);
        collectTags = $(this).parent().attr("class").split(' ');
        function createTag(it) {
            return format("<a href='$site$it'>$it</a>", {
                site: (it == 'wedding' || it == 'concert') ? 'http://example.com/gallery/#filter=.' : 'http://example.com/gallery/#filter=.',
                it: it
            });

        }
        filterTags = ['churchevent', 'corporate'];
        filteredTags = tags.filter(function(itm){return itm!== filterTags});

        tags = $.map(collectTags, createTag);
        return  [].concat(caption ? [caption, link] : link).concat(filteredTags.slice(1).join(', ')).join('<br>');
    }
  }, visibleLinks.index( this ) );

  return false;   
});
```

Comment: You're defining `tags` after you're using it to filter, that's not going to work. Additionally, your `tags.filter` function isn't going to work, you need to check if `itm` exists in the `filterTags` array, not if they are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm supposing that, since you wrote "remove multiple specific elements" you want to REMOVE filterTags.

If that's the case then change this:

```
filterTags = ['churchevent', 'corporate'];
filteredTags = tags.filter(function(itm){return itm!== filterTags});

tags = $.map(collectTags, createTag);
return  [].concat(caption ? [caption, link] : link).concat(filteredTags.slice(1).join(', ')).join('<br>');
```

to this:

```
filterTags = ['churchevent', 'corporate'];

tags = $.map(collectTags, createTag);
filteredTags = tags.filter((item)=>{
    for(tag in filterTags)  if (item.indexOf(filterTags[tag]) != -1) return false;
    return true;
});

return  [].concat(caption ? [caption, link] : link).concat(filteredTags.slice(1).join(', ')).join('<br>');
```

else just use != -1 instead of == -1 in the filter method.

Comment: Using == -1 doesn't do anything. Using != -1 erases all of the tags.

Comment: Have you noticed that in my code I checked indexOf == -1 in filterTags ? I didn't change the operator only... take a better look.

Comment: I used your entire code and no tags are filtered out. There is no effect

Comment: My bad. There was a typo. `(itm)=>filterTags.indexOf(item)` should be `(item)=>filterTags.indexOf(item)`. Corrected.

Comment: I am now using `filteredTags = tags.filter((item)=>filterTags.indexOf(item) == -1);` and it still does not filter any array items out.

Comment: Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/a07v5ddx/ it does filter. Debug your code. Put a `console.log(tags, filterTags)` before filteredTags line and tell me the result.

Comment: `Array [ "<a href='http://example.…", "<a href='http://example.…", "<a href='http://example.…", "<a href='http://example.…" ] Array [ "wedding" ]`
About 20 times

Comment: ah... now it's clearer. By tags you mean html tags, not tags as in category. Ok so we need a way to know if a certain tag should be filtered or not. The HTML tag `"<a href='http://example.…"` has the word 'wedding' on it ? again put `console.log(tags[0])` before filteredTags and post the full result here.

Comment: `<a href='http://example.com/gallery/#filter=.grid-item-services'>grid-item-services</a>` but each div has multiple classes assigned to it. grid-item-services in addition to whatever catergory it is placed it. "concert, wedding, corporate" for example.

Comment: I see... wait a min

Comment: \o/ yes.. glad it worked. :) Now in your next question, keep in mind what happened here. You said tags, and we only discover you were talking about html tags by debbugging. In your next question, please be more specific and put all the info you can, so people can help you better. :)

Answer (score 0):

What is "tags" in the context of `tags.filter`? I'm assuming it is some array. In either case, your filter is checking that an item in tags is not equal to `filterTags`, an array. Of course a single item in an array won't be equal to an array, so this will always return true, thus not filtering anything.

I think you probably want something like:

```
filteredTags = tags.filter(function(itm){return filterTags.indexOf(itm) !== -1});
```

Comment: He said he wants to remove some tags. So that means that the filterTags should be removed, not validated. So it should be ==  -1

Answer (score 0):

Are you speaking about this array?

```
filterTags = ['churchevent', 'corporate'];
filteredTags = tags.filter(function(itm){return itm!== filterTags});

// Of note, you are creating tags just below this code. Should you move it up?
// Or rename tags => collectionTags???

// Either way, the filter function you are using is not doing what you expect.

tags.filter(function(itm){
  // itm will be whatever, I'm guessing a string of some sort like "churchevent"

  // Now you are trying to compare a string like "churchevent" to the 
  // array filterTags.

  // This is what is happening...

  return itm !== ['churchevent', 'corporate'];

  //  What you want to do is this in ES5

  return (filterTags.indexOf(itm) === -1);

  // or this in ES6

  return !filterTags.includes(itm);
  // Note the bang in front.
  // TRUE will put itm in the tags array, FALSE will not.

}
```

> Also, please reference the filter function in MDN.

[Filter Function (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: I tried the following and it just removed all of the tags


`filterTags = ['wedding', 'corporate'];
tags = $.map(collectTags, createTag);
filteredTags = tags.filter(function(itm){return filterTags.indexOf(itm) > -1});
return  [].concat(caption ? [caption, link] : link).concat(filteredTags.slice(1).join(', ')).join('<br>');`

Comment: I changed the answer from > === as I noted your question wanted not equal.